# How to access the ‘pk’ created by ‘self.client.post() test

Tags: django, unit-testing

Here’s my test:

```
def test_CreateEmployeeProfileView_redirect_on_success(
                                                    self):
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('service:create_employee_profile'), {
                'first_name': 'Test',        # Required
                'middile_name': 'Testy',     # Optional
                'last_name': 'Testman',      # Required
                'employee_choices': 'E',     # Required
                })
    self.assertRedirects(response,
        expected_url=reverse('service:customer_employee_profile_detail', kwargs={'pk':response.pk}),
        status_code=302,
        target_status_code=200,
        )
```

I know this works if I change `response.pk` to `1`. Is there a way to get the `pk` of the `post` object without querying it? Or does it not get a `pk` until after it is `post`ed and saved? The `pk` is an `autointegerfield`

model.py

```
class Name(models.Model):
key = models.AutoField(
    primary_key=True,
    )
first_name = models.CharField(
    "First Name",
    max_length=100,
    )
middle_name = models.CharField(
    "Middle Name or Initial",
    max_length=100,
    blank=True,
    )
last_name = models.CharField(
    "Last Name",
    max_length=200,
    )
    class Meta:
    abstract = True
    ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name']
class CustomerEmployeeName(Name):
CUSTOMER = 'C'
EMPLOYEE = 'E'
EMPLOYEE_CHOICES = (
    (EMPLOYEE, 'Yes'),
    (CUSTOMER, 'No'),
    )
employee_choices = models.CharField(
    "Employee",
    max_length=1,
    choices=EMPLOYEE_CHOICES,
    )

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('service:customer_employee_profile_detail',
                    kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

form.py

```
class EmployeeNameForm(ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = CustomerEmployeeName
    fields = [
        'employee_choices',
        'first_name',
        'middle_name',
        'last_name',
        ]

    widgets = {
        'middle_name': TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Middle Name (optional)',
                }),
        }

    error_messages = {
        'employee_choices': {
            'required': _('Required'),
            },
        }
```

view.py

```
def create_employee_profile(request):

if request.POST:
    name_form = EmployeeNameForm(request.POST)

    if name_form.is_valid():
        new_name_form = name_form.save()
        return redirect(new_name_form)

    else:
        return render(request,
                'service/template_create_employee_profile.html',
                    {'name_form': name_form}
                    )

else:
    name_form = EmployeeNameForm(
                    initial={'employee_choices': 'E'}
                    )
    return render(request,
                'service/template_create_employee_profile.html',
                {'name_form': name_form}
                )
```

Format is a little off. Kids are running amuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test a Django CreateView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111777/how-do-i-test-a-django-createview)

Comment: I’m testing that the`url` of the `redirect` is correct when the submitted form is valid, which includes the `pk`. This other one doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pk value(or the id) of the object is created automatically on the model level. Unless your view allows for the client to post a custom id with the payload

```
{
   'first_name': 'Test',        # Required
   'middile_name': 'Testy',     # Optional
   'last_name': 'Testman',      # Required
   'employee_choices': 'E',     # Required
   'pk' : 3 # Optional id you may provide if your viewset handles it
}
```

then the id (what you are referring to as response.pk) can only come back in the response after it is created in the database

Comment: So if I don’t want to use a ‘1’ for my `kwarg` I have to query the object and then use `object.pk` (pk as in primary key)

Comment: you would need to post the view code in order for me to get a better understanding. I suspect you may be mixing up post and put request in standard django rest practices.

Comment: need the entire function and class. that dictates what params are passed to the view code and what you are doing with 'pk' argument. also potentially the form code as well if you are using a hiddent field for pk

Comment: ok. I understand what is going on. You create an object via post request. It gets assigned an id via the data model. Then, you access it through a REST api call on a detail route /person/:id/. However the response does come back from the initial post request. I think the way you are doing it is fine but you also have the option to query the object. I would stay away from hardcodes ie ("1") in your tests. Also it doesn't appear that your form allows the client to post an ID to the backend

Comment: Yes, if I query the object it works. The `test` as posted here does not work. The `client` doesn’t post the id as it is created when the object is created. I just wasn’t sure if there was a way to access the id without queries. I kinda thought to stay away from hardcodes as it is discouraged everywhere else. Being new to programming, I’m trying to learn to do things with the best method. @Dap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170507/discussion-between-dap-and-carl-brubaker).